# Is there a way to keep the upper and lower case writing of words when searching for anagrams?

Tags: java, anagram

I need to write a program that reads an entire text file into a String and searches for anagrams in there. The output has to be all anagrams of the same type in a separate line with their original upper and lower case writing.

I've tried the following and it doesn't give me the results I want (it's all lower case obviously):

```
String input = inputStringBuilder.toString();
input = input.replaceAll("[^äÄöÖüÜßa-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
String[] sentence = input.split(" ");

Map<String, Set<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++){

        char[] charwords = sentence[i].toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(charwords);

        String key = new String(charwords);

        Set<String> anagramSet = anagrams.get(key);
        if (anagramSet == null) {
          anagramSet = new HashSet<>();
          anagrams.put(key, anagramSet);
        }

   anagramSet.add(sentence[i]);

}
```

Comment: Do you understand what an anagram is? I don't see anywhere in the code where you even attempt to check for anagrams.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Yes, I know what it does. And that's my problem. The entire thing doesn't work anymore if I remove it (since upper and lower case characters are not the same)

Comment: Move `.toLowerCase()` from the `input` statement to the `charwords` statement: `char[] charwords = sentence[i].toLowerCase().toCharArray();` --- You want to key to the case-less (before the `sort()`), but the words in the `sentence` array to have original case.

Comment: @Andreas That works, but it keeps the duplicates (which aren't anagrams of course)

Comment: What duplicates? You store in a `Map` and a `Set`, neither of which allows duplicates.

Comment: If a word is in there twice, e.g. "the" and "The" are printed as anagrams

Comment: So which of the two do you want to see, if you don't want both, but do want to retain case?

Comment: I don't want any of those. It's supposed to output anagrams only.

Comment: But if text also contained "eth", then you would have anagrams, so what would result be, if you don't want to see both "the" and "The"?

Comment: I don't want it to recognize the exact same words as anagrams.

Comment: So if text has "The" and "the" you don't want to see it, but if text has "The", "the", and "eth", you want to see all 3?

Comment: Kind of. Is it possible to output only one "the" and "eth" (since "The" and "the" are technically not anagrams)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to move the `toLowerCase()` call.

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^äÄöÖüÜßa-zA-Z ]", ""); // <== Removed from here
String[] sentence = input.split(" ");

Map<String, Set<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++){

        char[] charwords = sentence[i].toLowerCase().toCharArray(); // <== Added here

        Arrays.sort(charwords);

        String key = new String(charwords);

        Set<String> anagramSet = anagrams.get(key);
        if (anagramSet == null) {
          anagramSet = new HashSet<>();
          anagrams.put(key, anagramSet);
        }

   anagramSet.add(sentence[i]);

}
```

Next, you need to eliminate entries from the `anagrams` map that don't contain any actual anagrams.

This step is entirely missing in the question code, where map entries with a `Set` of size 1 are not actual anagrams.

Now that the `Set` contains words with their original case, non-anagrams like `"The"` and `"the"` might be present, and must be eliminated too, assuming there are no *real* anagrams. If there are real anagrams, the various casing variants should be retained.

To check for that, add **all the words to a lowercased set**, and eliminate if this new set has size 1, otherwise keep the case-preserving set.

```
// code from above here
for (Iterator<Set<String>> iter = anagrams.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Set<String> words = iter.next();
    if (words.size() == 1) {
        iter.remove(); // Not anagram: Single spelling only
    } else {
        Set<String> lower = new HashSet<>();
        for (String word : words)
            lower.add(word.toLowerCase());
        if (lower.size() == 1) {
            iter.remove(); // Not anagram: Multiple case variants, but all same spelling
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
Input:  This is a test of 'the' and 'The'
Result: {}

Input:  This is a test of 'the', 'The', and 'eth'
Result: {eht=[the, The, eth]}
```

---

If you don't want to retain all the case variants of the same word, then simply **make the set case-insensitive**, using `new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`.

*(Code condensed, some of it by using Java 8 features)*

```
Map<String, Set<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : input.replaceAll("[^äÄöÖüÜßa-zA-Z ]", "").split(" ")) {
    char[] letters = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(letters);
    String key = new String(letters);
    anagrams.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
            .add(word);
}
anagrams.values().removeIf(words -> words.size() == 1);
```

*Test*

```
Input:  This is a test of 'the' and 'The'
Result: {}

Input:  This is a test of 'the', 'The', and 'eth'
Result: {eht=[eth, the]}

Input:  This is a test of 'The', 'the', and 'eth'
Result: {eht=[eth, The]}
```